# Creating MySQL query for report

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working a lot lately on making reports and there is a common problem I keep running into. I run into this when making reports or when creating charts.

Say I have 2 tables:

stages:
id
stage_name (Sample data: Open, Won, Lost)

projects:
id
title,
stage_id

Projects and stages are related. The problem I have is when I join the table it's obviously only going to return results if there are any. So say I'm running a COUNT query and there aren't any results that are currently set to the "Open" stage. Well it won't show that stage. However I want it to show a 0 instead of just not showing anything. I have no idea how to do this and I've tried quite a bit. I'm not sure if this is something I should do with temp tables or not. I haven't done temp tables in years.

This is the type of query I would run:

SELECT COUNT(id), stage_name
FROM projects 
LEFT JOIN stages ON stages.id = projects.stage_id 
GROUP BY stage_id

Any help?

Comment: What are you creating reports in? Sounds more like a report problem than a query problem. A count an empty table is still going to return a 0 to signify no records found. It'd be up to your report to decide what to do with that zero.

Comment: No it's a query problem. I am running the query and that is the results I get back. I'm am manually creating the reports using PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select from `stages` and join `projects`:

```
SELECT stage_id , COUNT(projects.id) 
FROM stages  
LEFT JOIN projects  ON stages.id = projects.stage_id 
GROUP BY stage_id
```

Comment: I see. So what if I was selecting from 3 tables and there were 2 tables that could possible have 0's in them?

Comment: You need to decide which table should go into `FROM` and which tables should be joined. In the current case all stages are in `stage` table, so if you `left join` others, it will still return all rows from `stage` table regardless of number of the rows in joined tables

Comment: What I mean is there is a possibility that either table can have a 0. And the count is being GROUPed off both of the tables.

Comment: If either table can have 0 records, you need `FULL JOIN`. Mysql doesn't support it yet, but there is a workaround : http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/